# estimate an integral, not sure with the first step

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let

$$f_n(x)=\frac{\sin(e^{nx\cos x})+nx}{n}$$

I want to calculate

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{[0,1]} f_n d\lambda$$

So, I know $|\sin(x)|\leq1\implies \Big|\frac{\sin(x)}{n}\Big|\leq\frac{1}{n}$

I just want to estimate it, but I am not sure with the first one.

$$\lim\int\frac{\sin(.....)}{n}+\lim\int x=...+\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Or you could bound the integrand by $\frac{2}{n}$. That should do it by DCT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $h_n(x)=\frac{\sin(\exp(nx\cos(x)))}{n}$. It follows from your argument that, for every $x$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}h_{n}(x) = h(x) \equiv 0$. Furthermore, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $|h_{n}(x)| \leq g(x) \equiv 1$. Since $g(x)$ is integrable over $[0,1]$, conclude from the dominated convergence theorem that
\begin{align*}
 \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{[0,1]}{h_n(x)dx}
 &= \int_{[0,1]}{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}h_n(x)dx} \\
 &= \int_{[0,1]}{0dx} = 0
\end{align*}